# How to view the total number of participants who got 100 in the quiz?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a simple Quiz Engine similar to that one in the ASP.NET website. I have the following database design:

- **User:** `Username`, `Name`, `DivisionCode`... etc
- **Division:** `SapCode`, `Division`.
- **Quiz:** `QuizID`, `Title`, `IsSent`, `Description`.
- **UserQuiz:** `UserQuizID`, `QuizID`, `DateTimeComplete`, `Score`, `Username`

What I want now is to show an indicator in the Result page of each quiz that will show to the user the number of participants in the Employee's Division who **got 100 from the first time of taking the quiz**. (so if the user takes the quiz again, his second try will not be considered in this query). **So how to do that (How to show the number of participants who got 100 from the first time only)?**

```
    My Query which is not correct is:

    SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, COUNT(dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants]
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     (dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = @QuizID)
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.UserQuiz.Score
HAVING      (dbo.UserQuiz.Score = 100)
```

And the desired output should be like this:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I am struggling now in being able to determine the QuizID:

```
;with OrderedAttempts as (
     select Username,Score,QuizID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username,QuizID ORDER BY DateTimeComplete) as rn
     from UserQuiz
     WHERE     (dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = @QuizID)
), FirstAttempts as (
     select Username,Score,QuizID from OrderedAttempts where rn = 1
)
select
    d.DivisionName,
    COUNT(fa.Score)
from 
    Divisions d
        left join
    Employee e
        left join
    FirstAttempts fa
        on
            e.Username = fa.Username
        on
            d.SapCode = e.DivisionCode
group by
    d.DivisionName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest part of the query is find everyone who scored 100 on their first try:

```
;with OrderedAttempts as (
     select UserName,Score,QuizID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName,QuizID ORDER BY DateTimeCompleted) as rn
     from UserQuiz
), FirstAttempts as (
     select UserName,Score,QuizID from OrderedAttempts where rn = 1
)
select
    d.DivisionName,
    COUNT(fa.Score)
from
    Division d
        left join
    User u
        left join
    FirstAttempts fa
        on
            u.UserName = fa.UserName
        on
            d.SapCode = u.DivisionCode
group by
    d.DivisionName
```

Hopefully, from there, you can build up the rest of your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it, but I could not be able to mix it with my above query. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your overall requirements, which is why I stopped at the above (although I forgot to partition by QuizID, so I've added that). Could you add some sample data and expected results to your question if you want me to go further?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thank you for your efforts. I updated my query and added a snapshot of the desired output. As you will see in the desired output, the query should display all the divisions whether they have people with 100 or not.

Comment: @AliAhmed - okay, updated again. I may not have the column names 100%, but hopefully you can translate back to your original (especially because in narrative you have `User` but in your sample query, you have `Employee`)

Comment: @AliAhmed - and, obviously, at the moment we're still not filtering/grouping by `QuizID`, which I think might be a requirement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, again thank you a lot but there is something missing and I don't know how to put it in your query. As you know, I have two tables; Quiz Table and UserQuiz Table. I need to add the Condiition (WHERE     (dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = @QuizID)
) in order to show the results for specific quiz not any quiz. so how to do that?

Comment: @AliAhmed - I would *probably* put it either in the `FirstAttempts` CTE or in the `on` condition of the join between `User` and `FirstAttempts` - or you could put it in `OrderedAttempts` - the only place you *shouldn't* put it is in the final `WHERE` clause, because that would force the `left join` to become an `inner join` and lose you the 0 results.

Comment: I did it as shown in the EDIT part in my question above, but it did not work with me. What I want is to be able to insert the QuizID. Could you please have a look at it?